# Syntax error on token "package", import expected (Java)

Tags: java

I am trying trying to import java.lang.Math in Java on Eclipse and am getting the error in the title. Here is the beginning of my code:

```
import java.lang.Math;

package test1;
```

This error is popping up under "package test1;"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `package` statement must be first in the file, before anything, even imports:

```
package hw1;

import java.lang.Math;
```

Plus, you don't need to import `java.lang.Math`, or anything in `java.lang` for that matter.

The [JLS, Chapter 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html) says:

> A compilation unit automatically has access to all types declared in
>   its package and also automatically imports all of the public types
>   declared in the predefined package java.lang.

Answer (score 3):

Place the package declaration before the import statement

```
package hw1;

import java.lang.Math;
```

The `import` statement itself is unnecesary as all classes in `java.lang` are imported by default.

Read [Creating a Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html)

Comment: All java.lang.* package implicitly imported by default